# C# Setter doesn't work at all. It doesn't invoke any code

Tags: c#, .net, properties, setter

I'm trying to change `Cents` in following code. But i 've been stuck for almost an hour. I just can't change this Cents. Setter inside of Cents doesn't work at all. It doesn't change value and even when I make `Console.WriteLine("It's been written in Cents setter");` It's not invoked too.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        BankAccount a = new BankAccount(50,200);
        Console.WriteLine(a.Cents);

        Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }


class BankAccount
{
    public BankAccount(uint dollars,uint cents)
    {
        this.Dollars = dollars;
        this.cents = cents;
    }
    public uint Dollars { get; private set;}
    private uint cents;
    public uint Cents
    {
        get 
        {
            return cents;
        }
        private set
        {
            cents = 500; //It doesnt change
            Console.WriteLine("It's been written in Cents setter"); // I can't invoke it
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not calling the setter anywhere here.

Comment: You probably meant `this.Cents = cents;`

Comment: @KlausGütter. Yes you're right. I'm, ashamed that i didn't see it almost one hour. Thank you.

Comment: If this is your goal then why do you have a constructor that takes cents as input? You can calculate cents yourself from dollars (or viceversa)

Comment: @Steve I think you didn't understand what I meant. I don't want to calculate cents to dollars and viceversa. I just wanted an account with Dollars and Cents. E.g Account with 14 dollars and 250 cents = 16 dollars and 50 cents. Fortunately I found solution yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up the backing field `cents` with the property `Cents`. In the constructor for `BankAccount` change `cents` to `Cents` and the setter will get invoked.

Also in the setter you probably want to say `cents = value`

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct implementation

```
using System;

class BankAccount
{
    private uint _dollars;
    private uint _cents;

    public BankAccount(uint dollars, uint cents)
    {
        this._dollars = dollars;
        this._cents = cents;
    }

    // default constructor
    public BankAccount()
    {
        this._dollars = 0;
        this._cents = 0;
    }

    public uint Cents
    {
        get
        {
            return _cents;
        }
        set
        {
            _cents = value;
        }
    }

    public uint Dollars
    {
        get
        {
            return _dollars;
        }
        set
        {
            _dollars = value;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BankAccount account1 = new BankAccount(100, 5);
        Console.WriteLine($"There are {account1.Dollars} dollars and {account1.Cents} cents on your bank account");

        account1.Dollars = 200;
        account1.Cents = 28;

        Console.WriteLine($"There are {account1.Dollars} dollars and {account1.Cents} cents on your bank account"); 
    }
}
```